# If I roll over my retirement into an IRA, can I pay off my school loans at the same time without having that sum penalized?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira, roth-ira, student-loan

I want to roll over a lump sum of retirement funds into some type of savings account, but want to designate a certain amount of it to pay off school loans.

Can I do it without being taxed and/or penalized on the amount going to school loans? If so, is an IRA or Roth IRA my best options?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I do it without being taxed and/or penalized on the amount going
>   to school loans?

No. Any withdrawal from your IRA account which is not re-deposited into another IRA account within 60 days is considered a distribution and is taxable. Unless certain exceptions apply (and repaying school loans isn't one of them), you will also be charged an additional 10% penalty if you're under 59.5 years of age.